# Map function returning array with index instead of string value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, mapping

Observing strange behavior in my map function:

```js
let tpl = ({x}, y = `This is ${x}`) => y;
    
console.log( tpl({x:5}) ); //correctly returns 'This is 5'

console.log( [{x:1}, {x:9}].map(tpl) ); //expecting array of strings, instead get [0, 1]
```

It is possible to 'fix' this by omitting default variable `y`, and returning the template string directly from tpl. However, I would prefer to do the initialization this way and can't understand why it wouldn't still work.

Seems like a strange anomaly to me, does someone have insight on something I am missing?

Comment: Why exactly do you prefer to initialize it with `y` when you can just return the template string directly like you said? Is it because you are sometimes passing in an optional template string to override the default one?

Comment: This is a sort of contrived example of what I want to do (y for example, could be the result of a function call), but it's mostly about aesthetics; I like the concept of one character returns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your **tpl** function is provided `(value, index, array)` by JavaScript's map Array method. You've given `y` a default value of `This is ${x}`. But when you pass `tpl` as the callback to `map`, `y` is not undefined so the default value is not used. `map` is passing the index to your `y` parameter.

```
let tpl = ({x}, y = `This is ${x}`) => y
const arr = [ {x:1}, {x:9} ];
arr.map(tpl) // [0, 1]
arr.map((value, index, array) => tpl(value)) // [ 'This is 1', 'This is 9' ]
```

[Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

[Default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)

Comment: Thank you for this insight - this clarified my confusion.

Comment: Awesome, no problem @Conqueror